# Jenkins Gerrit trigger plugin gives encoded GERRIT_CHANGE_COMMIT_MESSAGE and GERRIT_EVENT_COMMENT_TEXT

Tags: jenkins, plugins, comments, commit-message, gerrit-trigger

Jenkins Gerrit trigger plugin gives encoded values for **GERRIT_CHANGE_COMMIT_MESSAGE** and **GERRIT_EVENT_COMMENT_TEXT**

How do I decrypt it - to make it human readable?

Comment: I thinik I got it! There is a dropdown option in the advanced section to make it encoded or human readable

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the job configuration:

1) Go to the Gerrit Trigger section

2) Click on "Advanced..." button

[image]

3) Choose your preference

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot @marcelo-Ávila-de-oliveira (Marcelo Ávila de Oliveira), it was very helpful! :)

Comment: Great! Could you approve the answer? Thanks.

Comment: I am still a new user to Stak overflow (in contribution end) so still need to get a lot of credits to approve :(

Comment: @KishanK everybody can approve (accept) your own answers regardless of the reputation value. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/create-posts

Comment: Oh got it... I got confused with voting and approving answer :) Thanks for the tip... I have approved it now...

Comment: @MarceloÁviladeOliveira thanks, that worked, but the variable gets the value _e.g._ `Patch Set 2:` which is not very useful for anything. I'd actually like to see the comment that the user wrote, because I'd like to use that information...